# How to count number in separate list in a list for python?

Tags: python, list

How can I count how many times 3 appears in a list of list such as `[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,5]]`
the output should be something like `[1,1,0]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method [`list.count(element)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
my_lists = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,5]]
[l.count(3) for l in my_lists]
>> [1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Pretty useful!then how abt words?such as check how many times apple appears in a list['applepie','applesmoothies','banana'] and return [1,1,0]?

Comment: In this example, there is a loop on each element of `my_lists` and for each element `l` (a sublist), we count the number of times "3" appears in this list. The [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) allows us to append each time the number of occurences to the resulting list, so as to get `[1, 1, 0]`.

Comment: If you want to know the number of times the string `apple` appears in the elements of the list `['applepie', 'applesmoothies', 'banana']`, you can't use `my_list.count('apple')` because the search is exact. You will have to use something like `sum(1 for s in my_list if 'apple' in s)`.